# How to get local state value in the function that is passed as a prop to other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I passed the function as a prop to the child component(address lookup), after the address is filled by the user, the child component passes the value into the function that was passed as a prop.

Parent component

The parent component calls the API to get the value for singleCreditRep.

```
...
const EditCreditRep = () => {
  ...
    const [singleCreditRep, setSingleCreditRep] = useState();

 
   const addressHandler = (address) =>{ 
      console.log(address);
      console.log(singleCreditRep) 
      setSingleCreditRep({ ...singleCreditRep , "address" :  address}) 
   }
   ...

    return( 
          ...
          <AddressForm 
                        closeButtonHandler={() => setAddressModalVisibility(false) }  
                        addressHandler = {addressHandler }                          
          /> 
     )
}
```

Child Component

```
const AddressForm = (props) => {
    
    ...
    const assignAndCloseModal = () =>{
        props.addressHandler(address);         //Calling the function passed as a prop, 
    }
    ...
}
```

**Problem**: I can see the address that is passed to addressHandler is accessible there but singleCreditRep is always undefined. Although, I can see the singleCreditRep data populated in fields.
Despite the singleCreditRep data being populated but for more testing, I created a button in the parent module that triggers addressHandler() on click, It consoles the singleCreditRep
data always.

I need singleCreditRep data there so I can update the address of this.

Edit: prop (typo) is changed to props

Comment: Can you please provide codesandbox link would be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: You should be accessing `props` object in your child component, not `prop`.

Comment: @ivanatias  it was a typo, changed to props but have the same issue.

Comment: I tried to replica your bug but my code works fine. I used 2 inputs for address and credit rep. Can you update the value of singleCreditRep by an input? As Aman's comment, can you provide sandbox demo?

Comment: As you have not set any initial state, it is being logged as `undefined`. If you want to have look at the updated value, try to log the value inside `useEffect` hook with `singleCreditRep` as dependency. State update is async so you won't get the correct value immediately after updating it.

Comment: I'm just creating a sandbox demo. Will share soon

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-worker-6z5du4   I created the sandbox but this one is able to print the parent state "singleCreditRep" in the "addressHandler" function. I realize the parent renders when the value is submitted by a child. For example the sandbox has a static value so it prints but in a real scenario, it is an API call so it prints undefined.   @AmanSadhwani

Comment: @NeilNguyen can you please check the sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/white-worker-6z5du4

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect you have not passed any dependency array that's the reason for every change in the component, component re-renders request you to go through react docs and check how useEffect works.

Try this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    loadCreditRep();
    SetAddressModalHtml(<AddressForm addressHandler={addressHandler} />);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please check it now https://codesandbox.io/s/white-worker-6z5du4

Comment: if you console you will see an empty singleCreditRep object

Comment: I have made the changes in the code but now it does not show the local state, you can see that here https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dijkstra-qs9oz6?file=/src/Creditrep.js